# Problems with Sudo commands

Tags: sudo

I've been trying to install lamp server onto my ubuntu 12.04 LTS and i cannot get the sudo command to work. Been getting the following error everytime i hit/install anything with sudo.[image]

[image: After performing the Operation suggested by @oli]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Reboot into recovery. Hold <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> at boot, select "Other options" then pick the latest recovery mode.
2. Pick "root shell prompt" when the recovery menu loads.
3. Run the following:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   chown -R root: /etc/sudoers{,.d}
   chmod -R 440 /etc/sudoers{,.d}
   chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d 
   reboot
   ```

Comment: thank you finally got it. I swear now i won't mess with the permissions. let alone leave it as it is.

Comment: @KanthalaRaghu , it would make your question "more complete" if you mention **in the question itself** that you had modified the sudoers file or its permissions. In general, any supplementary information you add should be incorporated in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to boot into the recovery mode to fix this problem.

[Tutorial](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo)

In case 3 (Tutorial) instead of the chmod command, you need to use:-

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers
```